# How can I make the routes in Vuejs work with the library i18n?

Tags: vue.js, routes, router, vue-router, vue-i18n

I'm making a page where you can choose the language with the library vue-i18n. The problem arises when I want children routes.

It does not load the children routes. But if I do it without children, it is loaded.

Also the error that shows is this: *You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.*

I searched about this error and the solution is:

```
 resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

but I do not use webpack

**This is my code (Router)**

```
export default new Router({
routes: [
    {
        path: '/:lang',
        component: {
            template: '<router-view></router-view>'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'quiz',
                name: 'Quiz',
                component: Quiz
            },
            {
                name: 'QuestionsCRUD',
                path: 'crud',
                component: QuestionsCRUD
            }
        ]
    }
],
mode: 'history'
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <TheLanguageSwitcher/>
    <router-view/>
</div>
```

The code I saw it from the i18n documentation: https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-i18n-starter